# How to resolve "Fatal error: Call to a member function query()"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, dreamhost

Just had the *database.php* file changed from from MySQL to PDO. But I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/mypath/mydomain.com/library/database.php on line 19

It's working fine on the site of the individual who made the change. But when uploaded to my site it's generating this error, not sure why. I use DreamHost. What's wrong?

**Line 19:**

```
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
```

**Code prior:**

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=onlysecret_db", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

function dbQuery($sql)
{
  global $pdo;
  $result = $pdo->query($sql);  
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: *"$result = $pdo->query($sql);"* - that isn't much of a title.  Terrible, actually.

Comment: Your PDO connection is `$conn`, not `$pdo`...

Comment: Look at your variables ***very carefully***

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're accessing `$pdo`, which is a variable that doesn't exist.

Change `$pdo` to `$conn`:

```
function dbQuery($sql)
{
    global $conn;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);    
    return $result;
}
```

...but I would advise against using `global` and instead pass the `$conn` as a parameter to the function.